# google maps - how to adjust scroll sensitivity

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Recently when using google maps, the scroll sensitivity has been off the chart. On my touchpad, moving my finger about 2mm will go from a scale of about 100ft to seeing the entire globe.

Is there any way to adjust the scroll wheel sensitivity so that this won't be so touchy?

*Edit: using debugger tools in the browser, I was able to find that the zoom was using the `wheel` event. I tried adding an event listener in the console, but it was never called.

```
window.addEventListener('wheel', e => {
  console.log(e)
})
```

I'm guessing google already has an event listener which has a `stopPropagation`. Is there anything I can do in this case to intercept/change these events to reduce the sensitivity?

Answer (score 1):

Since google already has an event listener registered, adding any normal event listener to try to adjust would come after their event listener, and wouldn't do any good, even if they weren't stopping propagation.

Fortunately there is something called "capturing" event listeners, which always happen before regular non-capturing event listeners. (details on capturing can be found in [MDN addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) docs. So if we register a capturing event listener, we can catch the event before google gets it.

In this case since we just want it to be less sensitive, we can accomplish that by cancelling a bunch of scroll events. After some trial and error, I found that keeping 1 event out of 25 gave the sensitivity I wanted. I parameterized the 25 though, so that it's easy to adjust as needed.

```
((s) => {
  let x = 0;
  window.addEventListener('wheel', e => {
    if (x++ % s === 0) return;
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
  }, { capture: true });
})(25);
```

You can apply this using something like the greasemonkey plugin, or you can just make it a bookmarklet (create a bookmark, and the URL will be `javascript:` followed by the above script). Then you just click the bookmarklet once you load google maps, before you scroll.